# Excel VBA delete email after sending

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

might be you are able to help me with VBA code.

I got a code that send as PDF part of excel sheet. 
Problem is that email is used by many people and sometimes text is confidential. Is there an option to delete email (sent items and deleted items) after email is sent?

Using office 2000

Here is my existing code.

```
Sub SendDDocs()
  Dim IsCreated As Boolean
  Dim PdfFile As String, Title As String
  Dim OutlApp As Object
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Range("A1:J103")

  Title = Range("o1")


  Title = Range("o1").Value & " Confidetial"
  PdfFile = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" & Title & ".pdf"

  With ActiveSheet
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
  End With

  On Error Resume Next
  Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  If Err Then
    Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    IsCreated = True
  End If
  OutlApp.Visible = True
  On Error GoTo 0

  With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)

    .Subject = Title
    .To = "email@email.com"
    .CC = "email@email.com"
    .Body = "" & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "a" & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "" & vbLf _
          & Application.UserName & vbLf & vbLf
    .Attachments.Add PdfFile

    Application.Visible = True
    .Display
  End With

Kill PdfFile

  If IsCreated Then OutlApp.Quit

  Set OutlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You are talking about confidential data sent with an unencrypted email *"Using office 2000"* Are you serious? This Office version is out of security updates since almost 10 years. You should consider an upgrade for security reasons. • And you should consider not transferring confidential data through unsecured channels.

Comment: Yes I am talking about that. Unfortunately got no option to update version at the moment. As company will change software just in 2020. Sent data is not a big secret. So, I believe just delete from email would be enough, I hope so :)

Comment: Actually your biggest security issue is the person who decided to *"change software just in 2020"* • Nevertheless the email is not sent with your code but just displayed see `.Display`. If you change it to `.Send` you can `.Delete` it after it was sent.

Comment: Yes, firstly Outlook show email and Send button is clicked manually. It is done in purpose to avoid not sent email (had experience with that)

Comment: The email can only automatically be deleted if it is sent automatically. If the user sends it manually he is responsible of his confidential data and must delete it himself.

Comment: Thank you for feedback. Could you please advise how to do it automatically?

Comment: As I said in my comment before. Instead of `.Display` use `.Send` and `.Delete`.

Comment: With .send understood. But with .delete does´t work.. Just .delete after .display?

Comment: *"does not work"* is a useless error description (what error do you get? What happens?). And *Instead of* `.Display` means that you have to remove `.Display` and replace it with `.Send` and `.Delete` (each in one single code line).

Comment: done like you advised. Email is sent, but code return an error Run-time error, The item has been moved or deleted. And in after debug .Delete is painted in yellow. In the same time email is sent, but remain in sent items

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `.Display` use

```
.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
.Send
```

to not save a copy in sent items.

See [MailItem.DeleteAfterSubmit Property (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.DeleteAfterSubmit).